# SQL query for most matching tags

Tags: sql, tags

Let's imagine abstract database, which contains objects with attached tags (default many-to-many relation with additional table). Now, we have a user, who wants to find objects matching *the most* of tags he provides, sorted by relevance. For example:

```
Object1: TagA, TagB, TagC, TagD
Object2: TagA,       TagC, TagD
Object3: TagB,             TagD, TagE, TagF
Object4: TagA, TagB, TagC,       TagE
```

User asks for TagB, TagC, TagD
Expected result should look like following:

```
Object1 (3 matches)
Object4 (2 matches)
Object2 (2 matches)
Object3 (1 match)
```

---

**Edit:** Sample structure (I created it in SQLite, but we may safely assume MSSql)

```
CREATE TABLE Objects(Id int not null primary key, Name text);
CREATE TABLE Tags(Id int not null primary key, Name text);
CREATE TABLE ObjectTag(Id int not null primary key, ObjectId int, TagId int);

INSERT INTO Objects(Id, Name) VALUES (1, "Object1");
INSERT INTO Objects(Id, Name) VALUES (2, "Object2");
INSERT INTO Objects(Id, Name) VALUES (3, "Object3");
INSERT INTO Objects(Id, Name) VALUES (4, "Object4");

INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (1, "TagA");
INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (2, "TagB");
INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (3, "TagC");
INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (4, "TagD");
INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (5, "TagE");
INSERT INTO Tags(Id, Name) VALUES (6, "TagF");

INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (3, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (4, 1, 4);

INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (5, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (6, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (7, 2, 4);

INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (8, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (9, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (10, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (11, 3, 6);

INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (12, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (13, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (14, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO ObjectTag(Id, ObjectId, TagId) VALUES (15, 4, 5);
```

Expected result (for query "TagB, TagC, TagD"):

```
ObjectName | MatchCount
-----------+-----------
Object1    | 3
Object4    | 2
Object2    | 2
Object3    | 1
```

Comment: Can you please share your table(s)' structure? Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your table structure but from your post looks like you can use `GROUP BY` to achieve this like

```
select object, count(tag) as tagcount
from tags
where tag in ('TagB', 'TagC', 'TagD')
group by object;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer:

```
SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t1.tag) as count FROM
    (SELECT o.Name as name, 
        1 as tag 
     FROM Objects AS o,
        ObjectTag AS ot 
     WHERE o.Id = ot.ObjectId 
         AND ot.TagId IN (2,3,4)) AS t1
     GROUP BY t1.name
     ORDER BY count DESC
```